# Make Wix run embedded MSIs depending on selection

Tags: wix, installation

I'm trying to create installer which executes `CustomActions` or `MsiPackage` depending on components selection (e.g., run certain action/package if certain component is selected) and certain conditions checks. But I want to avoid creating `INSTALLDIR`, copying dummy file there and removing that dir.

I'd also like to avoid implementing custom handlers in C#, because I have no experience with it.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not likely you can install MSI packages sucessfully from within an MSI install because recursive MSI installs are not allowed. There will also be issues with repair and uninstall of your app and those MSIs depending on how you try to do this.  It's not clear what INSTALLDIR has to do with this either because you don't need an installdir to run custom actions. If the MSI packages are prerequisites why not just install them? If they are part of the app in some way then look at using Burn with a bundle to install them. I think more info is needed.

Comment: The main idea is to use UI to select/deselect certain packages. If I'm not mistaken, it is not possible via Burn which just runs the embedded MSIs. So, one of the ideas was to simulate the installation process to have normal UI with components selection, install some bogus files (like dummy text files), bind them to `CustomAction`s and remove the installed dummy stuff after that.